# efibootmgr cannot launch OSX yosemite (only showing folder image with question mark)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, macosx

I have a macbook pro with freshly installed yosemite (100 GB) and freshly installed Ubuntu. To boot I use efibootmgr. My partition layout is:

```
/dev/sda1         40    409639    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2     409640 196548327 196138688  93.5G Apple Core storage
/dev/sda3  196548328 197817863   1269536 619.9M Apple boot
/dev/sda4  197818368 930240511 732422144 349.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5  930240512 977104895  46864384  22.4G Linux swap
```

in efi bootmgr it looks like this:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0080* Mac OS X
Boot0081* Mac OS X
Boot0082* 
BootFFFF*
```

I have used

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0,80
```

as described in many places to boot into Ubuntu by standard and the 80 or 0080 (Max OS X) should be booted when I exit grub.
This does however not happen. When I hit "c" and write "exit" in grub the only thing that happens is that an image of a blue folder with a question mark is displayed. I have already tried 81 and 82 as well, same behaviour.

How can I dual boot Ubuntu and OS X with efibootmgr? The only way to boot OS X at the moment is to hit alt during startup and choose the efi partition which is a bit inconvenient.

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By chance I could fix it myself. The command parameters "-o 0,80" as written in many tutorials on the net simply don't work and even more irritating efibootmgr does not complain a second about it.

The correct command is

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0000,0080
```

Like that everything works fine.